# How to calculate centroids for 2 digit postalcodes using coordinates from 4 digit postalcodes

Tags: python

I have the following data in a txt file:

```
BE  1060    Bruxelles Saint-Gilles  Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8167 4.3333  4
BE  1060    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1070    Bruxelles Anderlecht    Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8333 4.3 4
BE  1070    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1080    Bruxelles Molenbeek-Saint-Jean  Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.85   4.3167  4
BE  1080    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1081    Bruxelles Koekelberg    Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8667 4.3333  4
BE  1082    Bruxelles Berchem-Sainte-Agathe Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8667 4.2833  4
BE  1083    Bruxelles Ganshoren Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8667 4.3 4
BE  1090    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1090    Bruxelles Jette Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8667 4.3333  4
BE  1110    OTAN - NATO Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8765 4.422   1
BE  1120    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1120    Bruxelles Neder-over-Heembeek   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  3
BE  1130    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1140    Bruxelles Evere Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8667 4.4 4
BE  1140    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1150    Bruxelles Woluwe-Saint-Pierre   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8333 4.4167  4
BE  1150    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1160    Bruxelles Auderghem Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8167 4.4333  4
BE  1160    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1170    Bruxelles Watermael-Boitsfort   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8    4.4 4
BE  1170    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1180    Bruxelles   Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8466 4.3528  4
BE  1180    Bruxelles Uccle Bruxelles-Capitale  BRU Bruxelles   BRU         50.8    4.3167  4
```

I would like to calculate the centroid of each 2 digit postalcode (10 and 11). How can I get the coordinates of all 10xx and all 11xx postalcodes as input value for my centroid formula?

The result should be something like:
BE 10 50.856 4.423
BE 11 50.8478 4.312
BE 12 etc.

Comment: Please post what you already tried. For example, you could read the cvs, import the postcode as string, and do a collection of a list of posititons, which you'd then average.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is a quick-and-dirty script. You might have to tweak it a little.

```py
import csv

codes = {}

with open("data.csv", "r") as file:
    reader = csv.reader(file, delimiter = "\t")
    for line in reader:
        short_code = line[1][:2]
        lat = float(line[9])
        lon = float(line[10])

        if not short_code in codes:
            codes[short_code] = []

        codes[short_code].append((lat, lon))

for short_code in codes:
    lat_sum = 0
    lon_sum = 0

    for point in codes[short_code]:
        lat_sum += point[0]
        lon_sum += point[1]

    lat_avg = lat_sum / len(codes[short_code])
    lon_avg = lon_sum / len(codes[short_code])

    print("BE %s %.4f %.4f" % (short_code, lat_avg, lon_avg))
```

Comment: short_code = line[1][:2] is exactly what I was looking for. Thank you, much appreciated!

Comment: How can I achieve the same with a file which has several different countries (first column) in it?

Comment: I haven't tried it, but I think `short_code = "%s %s" % (line[0], line[1][:2])`, `short_code = line[0] + " " + line[1][:2]`, or `short_code = " ".join([line[0], line[1][:2]])` should do the trick.